# How to improve accuracy of Tensorflow camera demo on iOS for retrained graph

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have an Android app that was modeled after the Tensorflow Android demo for classifying images,

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android

The original app uses a tensorflow graph (.pb) file to classify a generic set of images from Inception v3 (I think)

I then trained my own graph for my own images following the instruction in Tensorflow for Poets blog,

https://petewarden.com/2016/02/28/tensorflow-for-poets/

and this worked in the Android app very well, after changing the settings in,

ClassifierActivity

```
private static final int INPUT_SIZE = 299;
private static final int IMAGE_MEAN = 128;
private static final float IMAGE_STD = 128.0f;
private static final String INPUT_NAME = "Mul";
private static final String OUTPUT_NAME = "final_result";
private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/optimized_graph.pb";
private static final String LABEL_FILE =  "file:///android_asset/retrained_labels.txt";
```

To port the app to iOS, I then used the iOS camera demo,
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios/camera

and used the same graph file and changed the settings in,

CameraExampleViewController.mm

```
// If you have your own model, modify this to the file name, and make sure
// you've added the file to your app resources too.
static NSString* model_file_name = @"tensorflow_inception_graph";
static NSString* model_file_type = @"pb";
// This controls whether we'll be loading a plain GraphDef proto, or a
// file created by the convert_graphdef_memmapped_format utility that wraps a
// GraphDef and parameter file that can be mapped into memory from file to
// reduce overall memory usage.
const bool model_uses_memory_mapping = false;
// If you have your own model, point this to the labels file.
static NSString* labels_file_name = @"imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings";
static NSString* labels_file_type = @"txt";
// These dimensions need to match those the model was trained with.
const int wanted_input_width = 299;
const int wanted_input_height = 299;
const int wanted_input_channels = 3;
const float input_mean = 128f;
const float input_std = 128.0f;
const std::string input_layer_name = "Mul";
const std::string output_layer_name = "final_result";
```

After this the app is working on iOS, however...

The app on Android performs much better than iOS in detecting classified images.
If I fill the camera's view port with the image, both perform similar. But normally the image to detect is only part of the camera view port, on Android this doesn't seem to impact much, but on iOS it impacts a lot, so iOS cannot classify the image.

My guess is that Android is cropping if camera view port to the central 299x299 area, where as iOS is scaling its camera view port to the central 299x299 area.

Can anyone confirm this?
and does anyone know how to fix the iOS demo to better detect focused images? (make it crop)

In the demo Android class,

ClassifierActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen()

```
rgbFrameBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(previewWidth, previewHeight, Config.ARGB_8888);
    croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE, Config.ARGB_8888);

frameToCropTransform =
        ImageUtils.getTransformationMatrix(
            previewWidth, previewHeight,
            INPUT_SIZE, INPUT_SIZE,
            sensorOrientation, MAINTAIN_ASPECT);

cropToFrameTransform = new Matrix();
frameToCropTransform.invert(cropToFrameTransform);
```

and on iOS is has,

CameraExampleViewController.runCNNOnFrame()

```
const int sourceRowBytes = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
  const int image_width = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
  const int fullHeight = (int)CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);

  CVPixelBufferLockFlags unlockFlags = kNilOptions;
  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, unlockFlags);

  unsigned char *sourceBaseAddr =
      (unsigned char *)(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer));
  int image_height;
  unsigned char *sourceStartAddr;
  if (fullHeight <= image_width) {
    image_height = fullHeight;
    sourceStartAddr = sourceBaseAddr;
  } else {
    image_height = image_width;
    const int marginY = ((fullHeight - image_width) / 2);
    sourceStartAddr = (sourceBaseAddr + (marginY * sourceRowBytes));
  }
  const int image_channels = 4;

  assert(image_channels >= wanted_input_channels);
  tensorflow::Tensor image_tensor(
      tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
      tensorflow::TensorShape(
          {1, wanted_input_height, wanted_input_width, wanted_input_channels}));
  auto image_tensor_mapped = image_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();
  tensorflow::uint8 *in = sourceStartAddr;
  float *out = image_tensor_mapped.data();
  for (int y = 0; y < wanted_input_height; ++y) {
    float *out_row = out + (y * wanted_input_width * wanted_input_channels);
    for (int x = 0; x < wanted_input_width; ++x) {
      const int in_x = (y * image_width) / wanted_input_width;
      const int in_y = (x * image_height) / wanted_input_height;
      tensorflow::uint8 *in_pixel =
          in + (in_y * image_width * image_channels) + (in_x * image_channels);
      float *out_pixel = out_row + (x * wanted_input_channels);
      for (int c = 0; c < wanted_input_channels; ++c) {
        out_pixel[c] = (in_pixel[c] - input_mean) / input_std;
      }
    }
  }

  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, unlockFlags);
```

I think the issue is here,

```
tensorflow::uint8 *in_pixel =
          in + (in_y * image_width * image_channels) + (in_x * image_channels);
      float *out_pixel = out_row + (x * wanted_input_channels);
```

My understanding is this is just scaling to the 299 size by pick every xth pixel instead of scaling the original image to the 299 size. So this leads to poor scaling and poor image recognition.

The solution is to first scale to pixelBuffer to size 299.
I tried this,

```
UIImage *uiImage = [self uiImageFromPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer];
float scaleFactor = (float)wanted_input_height / (float)fullHeight;
float newWidth = image_width * scaleFactor;
NSLog(@"width: %d, height: %d, scale: %f, height: %f", image_width, fullHeight, scaleFactor, newWidth);
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(wanted_input_width, wanted_input_height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[uiImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newWidth, size.height)];
UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
pixelBuffer = [self pixelBufferFromCGImage: destImage.CGImage];
```

and to convert image to pixle buffer,

```
- (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBufferFromCGImage: (CGImageRef) image
{
    NSDictionary *options = @{
                              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                              (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey : @YES,
                              };

    CVPixelBufferRef pxbuffer = NULL;
    CVReturn status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                          CGImageGetHeight(image), kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) options,
                                          &pxbuffer);
    if (status!=kCVReturnSuccess) {
        NSLog(@"Operation failed");
    }
    NSParameterAssert(status == kCVReturnSuccess && pxbuffer != NULL);

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    void *pxdata = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pxbuffer);

    CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pxdata, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                                 CGImageGetHeight(image), 8, 4*CGImageGetWidth(image), rgbColorSpace,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
    NSParameterAssert(context);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0));
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake( 1, 0, 0, -1, 0, CGImageGetHeight(image) );
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    CGAffineTransform flipHorizontal = CGAffineTransformMake( -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, CGImageGetWidth(image), 0.0 );
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipHorizontal);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(image),
                                           CGImageGetHeight(image)), image);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
    CGContextRelease(context);

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pxbuffer, 0);
    return pxbuffer;
}

- (UIImage*) uiImageFromPixelBuffer: (CVPixelBufferRef) pixelBuffer {
    CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithCVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer];

    CIContext *temporaryContext = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef videoImage = [temporaryContext
                             createCGImage:ciImage
                             fromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer),
                                                 CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))];

    UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:videoImage];
    CGImageRelease(videoImage);
    return uiImage;
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way to resize, but this worked.
But it seemed to make image classification even worse, not better...

Any ideas, or issues with the image conversion/resize?

Comment: I added zoom support to the demo, and found its accuracy is improved when zooming in by a factor of 4 or 6, behavior is still quite different than the Android demo

Answer (score 6):

Since you are not using YOLO Detector the `MAINTAIN_ASPECT` flag is set to `false`. Hence the image on Android app is not getting cropped, but it's scaled. However, in the code snippet provided I don't see the actual initialisation of the flag. Confirm that the value of the flag is actually `false` in your app.

I know this isn't a complete solution but hope this helps you in debugging the issue.

Comment: In the Android demo version the MAINTAIN_ASPECT is set to true. In the iOS demo, I do not see this flag anywhere. The issue is not with Android, but iOS, we want the iOS demo to behave like the Android

Comment: But if `MAINTAIN_ASPECT` is set to `True` in Android that means the image is actually getting cropped to match the required size. Similar cropping has to be done on iOS and I think your issue will be solved. I'm not sure if there is a similar `MAINTAIN_ASPECT` flag in the iOS app that can be set to get the same behaviour. If not, cropping the image  through custom code should not be difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what the MAINTAIN_ASPECT cropping does exactly, does it chop off the top and bottom of the camera image and just take the middle? There is no flag in iOS, I included the iOS code in the post, any idea how to crop it?

Comment: The method that handles the scaling, cropping and other operations in Android are defined in the method  `getTransformationMatrix` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/5405f3bd7966663a005572e6cf0e870197f399d3/tensorflow/examples/android/src/org/tensorflow/demo/env/ImageUtils.java#L293). This can help you to replicate the operations on iOS. Since I have very little experience in iOS , i won't be able to help you replicate it. Cheers!

Comment: No, it is still not solved. Working code is needed to scale the CVPixelBufferRef to 299 pixels.

Comment: @James Try raising this as an issue on Tensorflow's github.. The getTransformationMatrix has to be replicated on iOS

Answer (score 2):

Tensorflow Object detection have default and standard configurations, below is the list of settings,

**Important things you need to check based on your input ML model,**

->  model_file_name - This according to your .pb file name,

->  model_uses_memory_mapping - It's up to you to reduce overall memory usage.

->  labels_file_name - This varies based on our label file name,

->  input_layer_name/output_layer_name - Make sure you are using your own layer input/output names which you are using during graph(.pb) file creation.

**snippet**:

```
// If you have your own model, modify this to the file name, and make sure
// you've added the file to your app resources too.
static NSString* model_file_name = @"graph";//@"tensorflow_inception_graph";
static NSString* model_file_type = @"pb";
// This controls whether we'll be loading a plain GraphDef proto, or a
// file created by the convert_graphdef_memmapped_format utility that wraps a
// GraphDef and parameter file that can be mapped into memory from file to
// reduce overall memory usage.
const bool model_uses_memory_mapping = true;
// If you have your own model, point this to the labels file.
static NSString* labels_file_name = @"labels";//@"imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings";
static NSString* labels_file_type = @"txt";
// These dimensions need to match those the model was trained with.
const int wanted_input_width = 224;
const int wanted_input_height = 224;
const int wanted_input_channels = 3;
const float input_mean = 117.0f;
const float input_std = 1.0f;
const std::string input_layer_name = "input";
const std::string output_layer_name = "final_result";
```

Custom Image Tensorflow detection, you can use below working snippet:

-> For this process you just need to pass the UIImage.CGImage object,

```
NSString* RunInferenceOnImageResult(CGImageRef image) {
    tensorflow::SessionOptions options;

    tensorflow::Session* session_pointer = nullptr;
    tensorflow::Status session_status = tensorflow::NewSession(options, &session_pointer);
    if (!session_status.ok()) {
        std::string status_string = session_status.ToString();
        return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Session create failed - %s",
                status_string.c_str()];
    }
    std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session(session_pointer);
    LOG(INFO) << "Session created.";

    tensorflow::GraphDef tensorflow_graph;
    LOG(INFO) << "Graph created.";

    NSString* network_path = FilePathForResourceNames(@"tensorflow_inception_graph", @"pb");
    PortableReadFileToProtol([network_path UTF8String], &tensorflow_graph);

    LOG(INFO) << "Creating session.";
    tensorflow::Status s = session->Create(tensorflow_graph);
    if (!s.ok()) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Could not create TensorFlow Graph: " << s;
        return @"";
    }

    // Read the label list
    NSString* labels_path = FilePathForResourceNames(@"imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings", @"txt");
    std::vector<std::string> label_strings;
    std::ifstream t;
    t.open([labels_path UTF8String]);
    std::string line;
    while(t){
        std::getline(t, line);
        label_strings.push_back(line);
    }
    t.close();

    // Read the Grace Hopper image.
    //NSString* image_path = FilePathForResourceNames(@"grace_hopper", @"jpg");
    int image_width;
    int image_height;
    int image_channels;
//    std::vector<tensorflow::uint8> image_data = LoadImageFromFile(
//                                                                  [image_path UTF8String], &image_width, &image_height, &image_channels);
    std::vector<tensorflow::uint8> image_data = LoadImageFromImage(image,&image_width, &image_height, &image_channels);
    const int wanted_width = 224;
    const int wanted_height = 224;
    const int wanted_channels = 3;
    const float input_mean = 117.0f;
    const float input_std = 1.0f;
    assert(image_channels >= wanted_channels);
    tensorflow::Tensor image_tensor(
                                    tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,
                                    tensorflow::TensorShape({
        1, wanted_height, wanted_width, wanted_channels}));
    auto image_tensor_mapped = image_tensor.tensor<float, 4>();
    tensorflow::uint8* in = image_data.data();
    // tensorflow::uint8* in_end = (in + (image_height * image_width * image_channels));
    float* out = image_tensor_mapped.data();
    for (int y = 0; y < wanted_height; ++y) {
        const int in_y = (y * image_height) / wanted_height;
        tensorflow::uint8* in_row = in + (in_y * image_width * image_channels);
        float* out_row = out + (y * wanted_width * wanted_channels);
        for (int x = 0; x < wanted_width; ++x) {
            const int in_x = (x * image_width) / wanted_width;
            tensorflow::uint8* in_pixel = in_row + (in_x * image_channels);
            float* out_pixel = out_row + (x * wanted_channels);
            for (int c = 0; c < wanted_channels; ++c) {
                out_pixel[c] = (in_pixel[c] - input_mean) / input_std;
            }
        }
    }

    NSString* result;
//    result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - %lu, %s - %dx%d", result,
//              label_strings.size(), label_strings[0].c_str(), image_width, image_height];

    std::string input_layer = "input";
    std::string output_layer = "output";
    std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
    tensorflow::Status run_status = session->Run({{input_layer, image_tensor}},
                                                 {output_layer}, {}, &outputs);
    if (!run_status.ok()) {
        LOG(ERROR) << "Running model failed: " << run_status;
        tensorflow::LogAllRegisteredKernels();
        result = @"Error running model";
        return result;
    }
    tensorflow::string status_string = run_status.ToString();
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Status :%s\n",
              status_string.c_str()];

    tensorflow::Tensor* output = &outputs[0];
    const int kNumResults = 5;
    const float kThreshold = 0.1f;
    std::vector<std::pair<float, int> > top_results;
    GetTopN(output->flat<float>(), kNumResults, kThreshold, &top_results);

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.precision(3);
    for (const auto& result : top_results) {
        const float confidence = result.first;
        const int index = result.second;

        ss << index << " " << confidence << "  ";

        // Write out the result as a string
        if (index < label_strings.size()) {
            // just for safety: theoretically, the output is under 1000 unless there
            // is some numerical issues leading to a wrong prediction.
            ss << label_strings[index];
        } else {
            ss << "Prediction: " << index;
        }

        ss << "\n";
    }

    LOG(INFO) << "Predictions: " << ss.str();

    tensorflow::string predictions = ss.str();
    result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - %s", result,
              predictions.c_str()];

    return result;
}
```

Scaling Image for custom width and height - C++ code snippet,

```
std::vector<uint8> LoadImageFromImage(CGImageRef image,
                                     int* out_width, int* out_height,
                                     int* out_channels) {

    const int width = (int)CGImageGetWidth(image);
    const int height = (int)CGImageGetHeight(image);
    const int channels = 4;
    CGColorSpaceRef color_space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    const int bytes_per_row = (width * channels);
    const int bytes_in_image = (bytes_per_row * height);
    std::vector<uint8> result(bytes_in_image);
    const int bits_per_component = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(result.data(), width, height,
                                                 bits_per_component, bytes_per_row, color_space,
                                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(color_space);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), image);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CFRelease(image);

    *out_width = width;
    *out_height = height;
    *out_channels = channels;
    return result;
}
```

Above function helps you to load the image data based on your custom ratio. High accurate image pixel ratio for both Width and height during tensorflow classification is 224 x 224.

You need to call above LoadImage function from RunInferenceOnImageResult, with actual custom width and height arguments along with Image reference.

Comment: Note the question was not how to get it to work on iOS, the app is working, the issue is that the image captured from the phone is not being nicely scaled/cropped to the required image size. Your code above is not scaling or cropping the image, unless I am missing something?

Comment: Please check my above-edited code, where I have included the load Image data based on a custom ratio. Let me know if you have any query in it.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, my code from the ios example had a pixelbuffer not a cgimageref so line LoadImageFromImage did not compile, even when I attempted to convert the pixlebuffer to cgimagref, think I ready to give up, add accept ios will not work as good as android

Answer (score 1):

Please change at this code:

```
// If you have your own model, modify this to the file name, and make sure
// you've added the file to your app resources too.
static NSString* model_file_name = @"tensorflow_inception_graph";
static NSString* model_file_type = @"pb";
// This controls whether we'll be loading a plain GraphDef proto, or a
// file created by the convert_graphdef_memmapped_format utility that wraps a
// GraphDef and parameter file that can be mapped into memory from file to
// reduce overall memory usage.
const bool model_uses_memory_mapping = false;
// If you have your own model, point this to the labels file.
static NSString* labels_file_name = @"imagenet_comp_graph_label_strings";
static NSString* labels_file_type = @"txt";
// These dimensions need to match those the model was trained with.
const int wanted_input_width = 299;
const int wanted_input_height = 299;
const int wanted_input_channels = 3;
const float input_mean = 128f;
const float input_std = 1.0f;
const std::string input_layer_name = "Mul";
const std::string output_layer_name = "final_result";
```

Here change : const float input_std = 1.0f;